# Entity Business Logic passed to Twig

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine, twig

I am trying to implement some simple business logic in my Entity to pass it to Twig but I seem to fail somewhere.

I have two entities **Users** and **Customers** who are extending an abstract entity called **Person** and share some field including **Gender**.

I want to create an isser in the Person Entity that gets the integer value of the gender(0 or 1), and converts it to a string of Male or Female like:

```
public function isMale()
{
    if($this->gender == 0) {
        $myGender =  "Male";
    }
    else {
        $myGender = "Female";
    }

    return $myGender;
}
```

so that I can pass this business logic in my Twig template something like:

```
{% for person in person %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ person.gender.isMale }}</td>
      <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The person attribute in Twig is a query passed from the Controller that holds some results in an array, which are the joined fields of both Entities.

I have created a Twig AppExtension as a filter, which works, and I simply want to pass this to the Entity logic but all I get is: **Impossible to access an attribute ("isMale") on a integer variable ("0")**.

Probably Virtual Property??

Answer (score 2):

In your twig template, you are treating `gender` as an object that has the method `isMale`. If gender was an entity/object itself, then what you have of `person.gender.isMale` would be valid. You should be able to have a working solution if you just change it to `person.isMale`

```
{% for person in person %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ person.isMale }}</td>
      <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do something like this:

```
person->gender() = 0;
```

Then:

```
gender->isMale();
```

But, you can see that `0->isMale()` is invalid.

So you need something like:

```
{{ person.getGender }}
```

Where `getGender` is a getter that returns a string representation of the gender (example "male").

Comment: I think this should answer your question. If you are asking something else, let me know, and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: `person->gender()` will thrown an error nonetheless as it is a property, not a method

Comment: @DarkBee has a very good point here. You don't call twig on a property, but instead use the methods - the getters, that's what they are used for.